# How to retrieve a total result count from the Sitecore 7 LINQ ContentSearch API?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In Lucene.Net, it is possible to retrieve the total number of matched documents using the `TopDocs.TotalHits` property.

This functionality [was exposed in the Advanced Database Crawler API](https://github.com/sitecorian/SitecoreSearchContrib/blob/master/scSearchContrib.Searcher/QueryRunner.cs#L63) using an `out` parameter in the QueryRunner class.

**What is the recommended way to retrieve the total result count using Sitecore 7's new LINQ API?** It does not seem possible without enumerating the entire result set. Here is what I have so far:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                       .Where(item => item.Content == "banana");

    var totalResults = query.Count(); // Enumeration
    var topTenResults = query.Take(10); // Enumeration again? this can't be right?

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq; // GetResults on IQueryable

var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                   .Where(item => item.Content == "banana");
    var results = query.GetResults();


    var totalResults = results.TotalSearchResults;
    var topTenResults = results.Hits.Take(10);

...
}
```

To get more info about sitecore and linq you can watch [this session](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/05/Inside-Sitecore-7-Session-2.aspx) and look at [this repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/SearchHangout).

Comment: This topic is also covered in this blog post from the Sitecore Dev team - http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/07/Sitecore-7-Making-Google-Part-3.aspx