# Sitecore 7 ContentSearch - Sort by random

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Using the ContentSearch Linq API in Sitecore 7, how might I go about efficiently taking a random selection of, say, 3 search results from around 1500 potential results?

So far I'm considering using the API to return an entire list of IDs (seeing as 1500 results isn't that large), and then doing the rest in code.

Can somebody point me in the right direction of what I'd need to do to be able to achieve this directly from Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with a smaller subset of items, it might be easiest for you to randomly shuffle the resultset of SkinnyItems using Fisher-Yates or any other shuffling algorithm.

```
To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
    for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
        j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
        exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

I'm not too familiar with Sitecore 7 yet, so if there's an easier way to do it I hope someone can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the custom sort option as described here: [Lucene 2.9.2: How to show results in random order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201638/lucene-2-9-2-how-to-show-results-in-random-order)
This, however did not perform any better than randomizing all the results, in our experience...
For that there are several options: [Linq to Entities, random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order).

Answer (score 0):

Stevie, have a read of this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540145/how-to-retrieve-a-total-result-count-from-the-sitecore-7-linq-contentsearch-api) which might give you some inspiration as to how to go about it.

Also recommend reading this [article on Sitecore Community](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/07/Sitecore-7-Making-Google-Part-3.aspx) as suggested by [Stephen Pope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930716/stephen-pope)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that seems to refer to retrieving the total number of results, which I am already successfully doing. My (perhaps weird?) situation is that I want my results to be randomly sorted, and I can't see which area of the linked article would help me do that?

Comment: Alright, doesn't this help 
".Where(item => item.Content == "banana");"
And just out of curiosity what are the 3 results you are trying to get? Have they got anything in common that can be used to filter?